# How do I delete messages in Gmail

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, I want to put messages into the trash from the Inbox,  but at the same time, I would like to delete the messages from the "Important" label and the "All mail" label.  Is there a way to hit the message only once and put into the trash?  I want to delete from these other labels but want to do it all at once. How?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the message, it is put in the trash, and then permanently deleted 30 days later.

So just click delete and the message will no longer appear anywhere besides in:trash. "all mail" is all the mail you have except things in spam and trash.

From the comments:

> The "Important" emails are also have a copy in the "All mail" folder.

Gmail doesn't use folders. It uses labels. Each message/conversation can have multiple labels. But each message only exists once. The software decides which messages/conversations to show you based on which labels you have told it to show you.

If there is a message about the company holiday party, and you decide that it needs to have the "work" label, and the "party" label; then if you are showing "all mail", or "work" or "party" that same message will be displayed.

If you then select the message and click delete, then the "trash" label is slapped on the message, and the 30 day clock starts.

Comment: Why do the emails in "Important" still remain in "All mail", even if I have deleted them in the in box and the same for emails in the Trash still remaining in All Mail?

Comment: A clarification of the above:   Why do emails remain in the "Important" folder after I have trashed the emails from the Inbox?  The emails that were sent to "Trash" also have a copy of the emails in the "All mail" folder as well.  The "Important" emails are also have a copy in the "All mail" folder.  I understand the Trash folder is suppose to be emptied 30 days later.